# How come "minus, space, minus" evaluates to the "plus" operator?

Tags: javascript

```
node -e 'console.log(- -1)' // prints 1 which makes sense
```

However:

```
node -e 'console.log(1 - - 1)' // prints 2 which does not make sense to me
```

`integer - - integer` magically converts "minus, space, minus" to the "plus" operator. Why?

**Update:** It seems I wasn't clear enough. The question is not why `double negative in mathematics will always evaluate to a positive` but how this magically evaluates to the `+` operator; these are two different scenarios - making a negative number positive is one thing, invoking implicitly the `+` is another thing.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/positive-negative-integers.html

Comment: Well, you are subtracting a negative number.

Answer (score 10):

Makes perfect sense, a double negative in mathematics will always evaluate to a positive

Comment: What about `1 --1` (note the missing space between the operators)? It is not implemented and throws an error.

Comment: @CPH4 The scanner doesnt work that way.. it parses token one by one and expects next tokentype based on the previous tokens in stack.

Comment: @CPH4 do checkout implementation here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3

Answer (score 4):

One of your `-` characters is a unary minus, or a negative sign.  That makes one of your literals a "negative one".  The other one is a subtraction.

```
1 - - 1
```

is the same as:

```
1 - (-1)
```

While

```
- - 1
```

is the same as

```
0 - (-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is interpreting `1 - - 1` as `1 - -1` which equals 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, "- -1" equals to "+1", so "1 - - 1" equals to "1 + 1" which equals two.

Answer (score 0):

In math `-- = +`. If I take `1 - (-1)` I get `2`. Subtracting a negative number is the same as adding the number...